# How do I create a shortcut key for Rust: cargo run?

Tags: rust, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I am just starting with Rust and VSCode.

If I hit <kbd>F1</kbd> and choose `Tasks: Run Task`, I see a list of tasks. If I choose the `Run: cargo run` task and hit `Enter`, it is executed in the terminal.

So three keystrokes are needed. Is there a way to assign a shortcut key so that this could be done with one keystroke?

Observation: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> makes a list with two items appear: `Rust: cargo build` and `Rust: cargo check`.

Comment: Does F5 not work for you? You could also rebind "Start without debugging (Ctrl + F5)" to whatever you want in `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`.

Comment: `F5` does not work even after making the changes suggested by Boiethios.

Answer (score 2):

I use this in my `launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug",
            "type": "gdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "target": "./target/debug/my_program",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "preLaunchTask": "Cargo build"
        }
    ]
}
```

of course, you must have a "Cargo build" task in the `tasks.json`:

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "Cargo build",
        "command": "cargo build",
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
```

Then when I press <kbd>F5</kbd>, I can run my program in debug mode.

Comment: Thanks. I made some progress. Still, when I hit `F5` I get this message on the terminal:`> Executing task: C:\Projects\bitbucket3\RustProjects\hello_test3\cargo build  <` . But nothing else happens. I used your `launch.json` (with another file name) and `tasks.json` and I installed the C/C++ and Native Debug extensions. In any case, even if I end up being able to debug, I realize that I do not understand the role of the `.json` files and what is happening. Is there a reference that explains all this?

Comment: I managed to do it using the `launch.json` from this URL: <http://www.brycevandyk.com/debug-rust-on-windows-with-visual-studio-code-and-the-msvc-debugger/>. It works but I get many messages like `Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file` on the Debug Console.`

Comment: Do you encounter the same messages with `Ctrl + F5` ? If not try swapping this Shortcut with a single key as I suggested in my comment.

Comment: @Soldalma I never used those things in Windows, only Linux, and it worked fine at first.

Comment: Working fine now, I am happy since that was my first day with Rust.

Comment: @Soldalma Oh, nice! Feel free to edit my answer if you think that you can add details about how to make it to work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Windows.

Step 1: Install rust and restart VS Code if you haven't already.

Step 2: Install these two extensions in VS Code:

Name: C/C++
Id: ms-vscode.cpptools
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools

Name: rust-analyzer
Id: rust-lang.rust-analyzer
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust-analyzer

Step 3: Open Settings in VS Code using `Ctrl+,` and set `debug.allowbreakpointseverywhere` to true. This allows you to set breakpoints in your `.rs` files.

Step 4: Add the following two files to your workspace

`.vscode/launch.json`

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "program": "target/debug/hello_world.exe", // change to your exe name
            "preLaunchTask": "Cargo build"
        }
    ]
}
```

`.vscode/tasks.json`

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Cargo build",
            "command": "cargo", // command "cargo build" did not work for me
            "args": ["build"],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Step 5: Pressing F5 should save all files, run the build task and debug the program.

If you're building a library instead of an executable, there should be a way to debug the test methods, but I haven't got to that point yet. Edits welcome to add this.